# Reference images from within a zip file, possible?

Tags: html

I would like to create an HTML file with image references which come form a zip file. The HTML file is for consumption on disk i.e., not through a internet server app like IIS or Apache. The intent is to open the html file with Word.

So for example a file test.html would contain a reference like:
 `<img src="test.zip/images/myimg.jpg" alt="Title" height="500" width="300">`
The test.zip file would be in the same folder as test.html.

Any idea if something like this is possible?  (BTW, I know how to do this with an (uncompressed) images folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, is the short answer. 
You have to extract this in order to read it. 
 
You have to keep in mind that the orginal image is nothing like the zipped image.